# tkinter Styles not being found

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to style my treeview

```
#Treeview Style
treeStyle = ttk.Style()
treeStyle.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Arial', 11)) # Modify the font of the body
treeStyle.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Arial', 13,'bold')) # Modify the font of the headings
treeStyle.layout("mystyle.Treeview", [('mystyle.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]) # Remove the borders

#treeview Frame Widgets Define
EmployView=ttk.Treeview(treeviewFrame,style=treeStyle)
```

However when I run the above code I get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: Layout <tkinter.ttk.Style object at 0x02FEAAF0> not found
```

I have clearly defined the style, so I'm confused as to why it is not being found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are not passing the right argument to the `style` option of the treeview. This option is not expecting a `Style` object but a string, in your case "mystyle.Treeview". The widgets' styles are just strings of the form `"<stylename>.<Layout>"` (if you don't put the `"<stylename>."` it will change the default widget's style) and they are managed / cutsomized using the `Style` object.

Comment: do you know how to change the size of the treeview?

Comment: @LyraOrwell What do you mean by the size? Look at the treeview's options there is a height option to choose the number of visible rows and you can also choose the columns width. The widget size also depends on the layout (grid, pack...) options you used.